# Getting Domain Controller (DC) Site name via Linux (windows "ntlest /sgetsite" equivalent)

Tags: linux, dc

I'm trying to extract the domain controller site name

On as windows system you can simply run `nltest /dsgetsite` and get the name.

From the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc731935):    "/dsgetsite Returns the name of the site in which the domain controller resides."

However, googling for a Linux alternative (E.G "Ubuntu") produced no results (nor did nslookup / dig / host).
Also, the account is not allowed to install any 3rd party tools/packages, so we can use only native commands (I'm aware that there are many distros.)

Is there any Linux equivalent for getting the DC site name ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Querying the AD Site on Ubuntu can be done using the `adcli` command:

```bash
adcli info domain.com | grep computer-site
```